# Only the last-appended onchange function for multiple select elements is called

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, onchange

I am programmatically creating multiple select elements with multiple options within each select element. I want to programmatically assign each select element with its own onchange function that will alert me the respective id for the select element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Headers indicate how many select elements I need.
    // In this example, they are only used to initialize a unique select.id
    for (var ndx = 0; ndx < headers.length; ndx++) {
        var header = headers[ndx];
        const rowName = header.innerHTML;
        var select = document.createElement("select");
        var options = ["Contains", "Equals", "Starts with", "More than", "Less than", "Between", "Empty",
            "Doesn't contain", "Doesn't equal", "Doesn't start with", "Is not more than", "Is not between", "Is not empty"];

        select.id = rowName + "-select";
        options.forEach(function(option) {
            var element = document.createElement("option");
            element.value = option;
            element.innerHTML = option;
            select.appendChild(element);
        });
        select.onchange = function () {
            alert("select.id: " + select.id);
        }
    }
}
```

However, upon changing any of the select elements' options, **only the id of the very last select element is shown in the alert**. Could this be a javascript referencing issue I am not familiar with? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Couldn't you use `this` instead of `select`?

Comment: The reason this is happening is because you change the select.id each iteration. `select.id = rowName + "-select";`, so it just outputs the last one. JS closures do store references to out of scope variables, but they don't store older values like you want them to right now.

Comment: @AP. wow, you are correct! That would also make sense as to why the id of the last element is only shown. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in javascript are hoisted to the beginning of the function scope in which they are declared. In practice, this means that with every iteration, you are replacing the variable select with the new select box. This means that all the listeners will refer to the same select variable, which at the end of the loop will contain a reference to the last select created.

**Solution**

Wrap the listener registration in a IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), passing it select as an argument. This way the value of select will be bound to the current iteration only.

```
(function(select) {
    select.onchange = function() {
        alert(select.id);
    }
})(select);
```

**Edit:**

A more correct way of implementing the listener would be to use the event object passed to it:

```
select.onchange = function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id); //e.target refers to the element that originated the event
}
```

But I'm leaving the above answer as well since there is also a problem related to hoisting/scoping in your code and it is a very common mistake.